# Require instantiates two times the class

Tags: javascript, node.js

I need to call a method of a class that should not instantiate again, because it raises this error:

```
Conflict: terminated by other long poll or webhook
```

Here is my main.js, running in my node service A:

```
var telegram = require('./telegram.js');
telegram.hello();
```

And my telegram class is running over a service B:

```
const bot = new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});

function hello(req) {
        console.log("hello!!");
}

module.exports.hello = hello;
```

What should I do?

Comment: I think you can achieve this by exporting it as an object like this `module.exports = {
  bot: new TelegramBot(token, {polling: true});
  hello: function(req) {
    console.log('hello');  
  }
}`

Comment: And there is no problem to communicate two services like this? probably the clean way could be use http?

Comment: Now I saw word service... I was referring to `include in multiple files`, and exporting as an object would give you a single instance. Regarding service communication http would be clean solution because service should have separate responsibilities and they should not interfere